# Laravel web.php: Storage::disk('local')->download($path): "download" is underline in red

Tags: php, laravel, storage

```
### 
    Laravel web.php: Storage::disk('local')-\>download($path): "download" is underline in red, any help?
```

> **web.php**

```
    <?php
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\ClientController;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\RolesController;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\UsuariosController;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\PermisosController;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\SelectController;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    
    Route::get('local/temp/{path}', function (string $path){ return Storage::disk('local')->download($path);})->name('local.temp');

"download" is underline in red(Undefined method 'download'.intelephense(1013))
```

**
Actually im traying to follow these instructions:
**
**Step 1: Add the following code in the AppServiceProvider boot method.**

Storage::disk('local')->buildTemporaryUrlsUsing(function ($path, $expiration, $options) {
return URL::temporarySignedRoute('local.temp',$expiration,
array_merge($options, ['path' => $path]));});

**Notice that URL::temporarySignedRoute receives route name local.temp, which we need to define.**
**Step 2: Add the route in web.php**

```
Route::get('local/temp/{path}', function (string $path){
    return Storage::disk('local')->download($path);
})->name('local.temp');

This will allow downloading of the file using a temporary URL.
Now you can easily generate a temporary URL for the local disk.

disk = Storage::disk('releases-local');return $disk->temporaryUrl($this->path, now()->addMinutes(5));
*************
THIS IS MY EDIT BLADE BUT IM NOT SURE IF I HAVE TO CALL DE TEMPORARYURL IN THIS FILE

<div class="form-group">                  
@if ($image)
Photo Preview:<br>
<img class="img img-circle" style="width:50px;" src="{{ return   Storage::disk('public')->temporaryUrl($image, now()->addMinutes(5)); }}"><br>                                                      
@endif 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="ImageControl" />Select photo</label>
<input wire:model="image" type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" placeholder="Image">
@error('image') <span class="error text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
</div>
```

Comment: Did you hover over the `download` for the coding hint? It looks fine to me.

Comment: Your IDE simply doesn't know that the `download` function exists on whatever `Storage::disk()` returns. Ultimately, does your code work? Getting an IDE to recognize every function can be a struggle, especially with frameworks, and especially if using older versions. If you need further help, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77107033/edit) and include your IDE, PHP/Laravel version, and any plugins you have enabled to assist with syntax highlighting and discovery.

Comment: try ``composer dump-autoload`` and then restart your IDE, most of time this works.

Comment: @aynber I did it and it says: Undefined method 'download'.intelephense(1013)

Comment: @TimLewis PHP:8.2.4 and laravel 10 and livewire, I want to get the photo preview before loading it

Comment: @MitKathrotia I dit it and still the same error

Comment: @TimLewis my code doesnt work, it says : syntax error, unexpected identifier "Storage", expecting ":"

Comment: You don't need temporaryUrl, but simply use the route helper : `{{ route('local.temp', ['path' => $path]) }}`. As for your error, it's hard to tell without the code, try to find where this error come from and show us the code that produce that error, i can see no error aside from the missing $ before disk which might be a copy paste issue. And also you don't need return when using interpolation (aka : `{{ }}`)

Comment: @Lk77 So where this code goes:  $disk = Storage::disk('releases-local');

return $disk->temporaryUrl($this->path, now()->addMinutes(5));

Answer (score 0):

This does not look better but you can get rid of the intelephense warning like so (by telling it exactly the class that is used here):

```
Route::get('local/temp/{path}', function (string $path){ 
  /** @var \\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse $storage **/
  $storage = Storage::disk('local')
  return $storage->download($path);
})->name('local.temp');
```